# How to define actuators using loop

Tags: python, game-engine, logic-bricks

I have several objects in my scene and each of them has an actuator (type Motion). The *object1* has the actuator *Motion1*, the *object2* has the actuator *Motion2* and so on. My problem is that I have 95 objects and I would like to define them in the code in a efficient way.

I've tried this:

```
import bge
import bpy
cont = bge.logic.getCurrentController() 
own = cont.owner

m = []
for k in range (1, 95):
    m[k] = cont.actuators["Motion"+ str(k)]
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done with [bpy.ops.logic.actuator_add](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_60_6/bpy.ops.logic.html)

```
import bge
import bpy
cont = bge.logic.getCurrentController() 
own = cont.owner

m = []
for k in range (1, 95):
    bpy.ops.logic.actuator_add(type='MOTION', name="Motion"+str(k), object="Cube")
```

Where type must be in ('ACTION', 'CAMERA', 'CONSTRAINT', 'EDIT_OBJECT', 'FILTER_2D', 'GAME', 'MESSAGE', 'MOTION', 'PARENT', 'PROPERTY', 'RANDOM', 'SCENE', 'STEERING', 'SOUND', 'STATE', 'VISIBILITY')

This was tested in the BGE using default scene with "Cube"